# Builder not giving output

Tags: python, kivy

I want to make a Multipage Application in kivy but when I use Builder.load_file, I get a Black screen. when i use base, I get the output. But then I can't change screens

The Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

class base(Screen):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('my.kv')


MYApp().run()
```

my .kv file:

```
<base>
    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        Button:
            text:'1'
        Button:
            text:'2'
        Button:
            text:'3'
        Button:
            text:'4'
        Button:
            text:'5'
        Button:
            text:'6'
        Button:
            text:'7'
        Button:
            text:'8'
        Button:
            text:'9'
        Button:
            text:'10'
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared the `root` anywhere. You have to define it either in `.py` (`.kv` unchanged) as,

```py
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('my.kv')
        return base()
```

Or, in `.kv` (`.py` unchanged) as,

```py
base:


<base>
    GridLayout:
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: will I be able to add more screens, earlier I was doing so, I wasn't

Comment: it throws the error

Comment: AttributeError: First letter of class name <base> is in lowercase

Comment: i am getting the same output without             Builder.load_file('my.kv')

Comment: 1. Yes, maybe using `ScreenManager`, 2. That's the [syntax of a kv file](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file), 3. That's because the `.kv` file's name matches the application class name.

Comment: I don't get it, Aren't we supposed to do that

Comment: Those are replies to your 3 queries.